# Fix Word Underline style in entire document

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a Word document which is about 100 pages long.  In it, there are many words that are underlined.

However, when I select the word, the Underline formatting icon isn't highlighted/lit up, showing that it's underlined.  Odd.

So, I checked in the immediate window, `?Selection.Font.Underline` and it returned `9999999`.  The words that *do* have the Underline icon lit up return `1`.

How can I quickly change all the underline styles that are `9999999` to `1`?

I've tried Find/Replace with "Underline" and replace with "Underline", but while it successfully found `999999` and `1`, the replacement didn't do anything.

I even macro'd that and did `Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline = 1` to no avail.

Currently, I'm looping through each paragraph, if the `para.Range.Font.Underline = 999999` is True, then loop through each character and where a character is `999999`, make that `1`.

So my question is how can I do this properly/faster?  Also, what causes the `9999999` in the first place?

edit: Here's the current code I have

```
Sub fixUline()
Dim doc     As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim para    As Paragraph
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Underline = 9999999 Then
     '   para.Range.Select
        For i = 1 To para.Range.Characters.Count
            If para.Range.Characters(i).Font.Underline = 9999999 Then
               ' para.Range.Characters(i).Select
                para.Range.Characters(i).Font.Underline = 1
            End If
        Next
    End If                   ' ...Underline = 99999
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next para
MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

edit: I also found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/l8fPuF7sJUM), but running the macro listed throws a compiling Type Mismatch error at the line `For Each oChr In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(para)`

Edit: Here are two screenshots. The first *is* an underlined word, but notice how Word doesn't seem to think so:
[image]

and the second is also underlined, but Word shows the underline selected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to un-underline everything in the document. Best way I can think to do this would be to "select all" (should be ctrl + A) and click the underline button (to underline the entire document) then click it again to un-underline everything.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove underline.  It's odd - for some reason, even thought I can see underlines, when selecting some words, Word doesn't show that they're underlined (meaning the "U" isn't highlighted in the toolbar).  When I do `?Selection.Font.Underline` I get a `9999999` as the result. When I do `?Selection.Font.Underline` on a word that is underlined, and the "U" is highlighted/selected in the toolbar, it returns `1`.  I want all my underlines to be `1` type.